# Changing Kubernetes' node-proxy tcp keepalive time

Tags: proxy, kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

How do I properly change the TCP keepalive time for node-proxy?

I am running Kubernetes in Google Container Engine and have set up an ingress backed by HTTP(S) Google Load Balancer. When I continuously make POST requests to the ingress, I get a 502 error exactly once every 80 seconds or so. `backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client` error in Cloud Logging, which is because GLB's tcp keepalive (600 seconds) is larger than node-proxy's keepalive (no clue what it is).

The logged error is detailed in https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the custom resource `BackendConfig` that exist on each GKE cluster to configure timeouts and other parameters like CDN [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/backendconfig) is the documentacion

An example from [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service) shows how to configure on the ingress

That is the `BackendConfig` definition:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-bsc-backendconfig
spec:
  timeoutSec: 40
  connectionDraining:
    drainingTimeoutSec: 60
```

And this is how to use on the ingress definition through annotations

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-bsc-service
  labels:
    purpose: bsc-config-demo
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"my-bsc-backendconfig"}}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    purpose: bsc-config-demo
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
```

Answer (score -1):

just for the sake of understanding, when you use Google solution to load-balance and manage your Kubernetes Ingress, you will have `GLBC` pods running in `kube-system` namespace.

You can check it out with :

`kubectl -n kube-system get po`

These pods are intended to route the incoming traffic from the actual Google Load Balancer.

I think that the timeouts should be configured there, on `GLBC`. You should check what annotations or ConfigMap `GLBC` can take to be configured, if any.

You can find details there :

- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/cluster-loadbalancing/glbc
- https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/controllers/gce/README.md
- https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/controllers/gce/rc.yaml#L64

Personally I prefer to use the Nginx Ingress Controller for now, and it has necessary `annotations` and `ConfigMap` support.

See :

- https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/controllers/nginx/README.md

Comment: The only GLBC-related pod is a single l7-default-backend.

If I understand correctly, GLB points to all nodes, and each node then proxies to the appropriate pod. If this is the case, the timeout issue is with the proxy within each node.